# How to print the window in angular?

Tags: angularjs, printing

Ive got many complicated sections and htmls with many ng-repeats.
I want to print the window when everything has been inserted into dom.
How to do that?Timeout is not a good option ..
events such ngContentLoaded and ngViewContentLoaded dont work.
Regards

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you need to do this? Why not use the dev tools to measure everything?

Comment: you could build your own `$event` which gets triggered if everything has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

ngRepeat directive set fields like `$first`, `$middle` and `$last` (among others) on local scope of the iterated elements accordingly if they are first, middle or last element of the iterated object. You can put a custom directive on the element with ng-repeat which will check if there is `$last` property attached to scope, if it is, it means the ngRepeat is finished. You can then print window.

This directive can look like this:

```
 app.directive('logOnRepeatReady', [
    '$window',
    function ($window) {
        var link = function (scope) {
            if (scope.$last) {
                console.log($window);
            }
        };

        /* make sure the directive has lower priority than*/    
        /* ng-repeat so it executes after ng-repeat*/

        return {
            link: link,
            priority: 0
        };
    }
]);
```

And use it like this:

```
<ul>
    <li log-on-repeat-ready ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```